# How to upload an svg to AWS S3 using Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, svg, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload an svg to AWS s3 in a rails application. Minimagick is being used to edit the images. I've added svg to my whitelist of extensions. Carrierwave is used to upload the images and Fog is used to connect to s3.

When I try to upload this the server log shows this:

```
    Started POST "/works" for ::1 at 2015-05-22 21:38:30 -0400
    Processing by WorksController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4j5bImtR8dws52vJ+Pt4lFnfj8Wt5Nn+e1HEMr0Q8u/pxz1rNqDMOSm3n/xGkr2PEXMSLS49Lq0IMXqsoPgVgg==", 
"work"=>{"name"=>"foobar", "github"=>"foobar", "uri"=>"foobar", "role"=>"foobar", "technologies"=>"foobar", "description"=>"foobar", 
"screenshots"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f90cb1f9ab0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/9k/cwvqf93d18n8lknkbhj6zyyh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150522-11807-1l0xzhy.svg>, 
@original_filename="blocipedia.svg", @content_type="image/svg+xml",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"work[screenshots]\";
filename=\"blocipedia.svg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/svg+xml\r\n">,
"screenshots_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save"}
    Unpermitted parameter: screenshots_cache
       (0.1ms)  begin transaction
       (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
    Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

I see that the content type header is set to svg+xml so I'm not sure why I'm receiving errors when I try to upload an svg file.

When I try to upload a png file I still get the `Unpermitted parameter: screenshots_cache` error but the image is uploaded successfully.

Here's the log when I upload a png:

```
Started POST "/works" for ::1 at 2015-05-22 22:04:00 -0400
Processing by WorksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SK7Ul/gEL018++ME8KKhh4LjLT8deSy2QzlZSP+MTNFDV7LepfUSqHmrFzFOy2Scyk+w156g2+UwWefW4mSrvA==", 
"work"=>{"name"=>"foobar", "github"=>"foobar", "uri"=>"foobar", "role"=>"foobar", "technologies"=>"foobar", "description"=>"foobar", 
"screenshots"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f90c1feee40 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/9k/cwvqf93d18n8lknkbhj6zyyh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150522-11807-gj91gj.png>,
@original_filename="react-on-rails.png", @content_type="image/png",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"work[screenshots]\"; filename=\"react-on-rails.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "screenshots_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Unpermitted parameter: screenshots_cache
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "works" ("name", "description", "github", "uri", "role", "technologies", "screenshots", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "foobar"], ["description", "foobar"], ["github", "foobar"], ["uri", "foobar"], ["role", "foobar"], ["technologies", "foobar"], ["screenshots", "react-on-rails.png"], ["created_at", "2015-05-23 02:04:01.545641"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-23 02:04:01.545641"]]
   (43.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/works/9
Completed 302 Found in 3868ms (ActiveRecord: 43.9ms)
```

Comment: Looks like you have an unpermitted parameter `screenshots_cache`

Comment: When I upload a png file, I still receive the unpermitted parameter message so I didn't think it was the issue. I edited the question to show the logs when I upload a png.

Comment: So what error are you receiving?  Am I just missing the error in your post?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error on my local server logs. However, when I try to save the svg to a work, the svg isn't accepted by or uploaded to the s3 server. Checking AWS S3 for its logs for further insight.